# How to filter same column on each intermediate table in Django join

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-orm

I'd like to join many tables and filter each one on the same column. My example is for checking for soft deletion, but I could imagine other applications, like filtering by a specific date.

For example, if my models are:

```
from django.db import models


class Members(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class Purchases(models.Model):
    member = models.ForeignKey(Members, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    item = models.ForeignKey('Items', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class Items(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey('Companies', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class Companies(models.Model):
    deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Members make purchases, purchases contain items, items are made by companies. Say I want to count the number of unique companies a member has purchased from, but I want to check each table to see if it's deleted. I can do this:

```
Members.objects.filter(
    deleted=True,
    purchases__deleted=True,
    purchases__item__deleted=True,
    purchases__item__companies__deleted=True
).annotate(num_companies=Count('purchases__item__companies', distinct=True))
```

But it seems silly to repeat the `__deleted==True` for every column. Is there a more efficient way filter the same column in the same way on each intermediate table in a large join?

Comment: Do you want to optimise that one instance of the query? Or are you worried about repeating it in multiple places? I don't think the former is possible, because you have to specify the fields to filter on. If there were some implied relationship (i.e. if Model X is soft deleted then we can assume the others are too) you could use that, but it doesn't seem to be the case. However, if it's the latter, then you can look at putting that query in a manager function so you don't have to repeat yourself elsewhere.

Comment: @malberts I am not concerned about repeating this particular query. I anticipate many similar queries (though not identical) that involve joining many tables and checking the soft delete column on each one. I want to simplify the code so that I don't have to specify that I am checking that column on every single table. It seems so unnecessary.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is really that much of an issue to write it out. When it is explicit, it is much clearer what exactly is actually happening. However, if you really want a magic function that can automatically check every related model's `deleted` property, then it should be possible to build a function into your model's Manager which will then analyse the fields for all relationships and whenever it finds a `deleted` field it will add it to the query.

Comment: Then you might end up calling `Members.objects.filter_deleted(True).annotate(...)` instead. However, I don't have an example because it seems like a bit too much work.

Comment: You could  possibly have a simpler Manager function which basically just pre-sets that exact filter. So it doesn't have to do model field magic, but instead you just move that part of your query above into the Manager function. Then you can reuse it for other Member queries where you do other things (annotate, more filters, etc) on top of the soft delete requirement. I can maybe do an example of this, if you want.

Comment: Interesting. I'll give that a shot.